# IIS throws 403 and this issue get resolve after IIS reset

Tags: iis, http-status-code-403, iisreset

I have a web application hosted on IIS with a separate AppPool. Without any changes, we are getting a 403 error and this error gets resolved on IIS reset.
We have few entity information like user details are stored in an in-memory cache.

Can you help me to understand why this is happening.

Comment: According to your description, we are not sure what caused this problem, can you view the log records in IIS?

Comment: Let FRT reveal the source of those 403 errors, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis and then it should be easy to know what's wrong and why IIS reset helps.